# Java - thread priorities (example from Thinking in Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I read now chapter about concurrency from Thinking in Java and I try to reproduce example from this book in my computer and I got very different results.

I do example from subchapter Priorities:

```
public class SimplePriorities implements Runnable {

    private int countDown = 5;
    private volatile double d;
    private int priority;

    public SimplePriorities(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Thread.currentThread() + ": " + countDown;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(priority);
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
                d += (Math.PI + Math.E) / (double) i;
                if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                    Thread.yield();
                }
                System.out.println(this);
                if (--countDown == 0) return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new SimplePriorities(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY));
        }
        executorService.execute(new SimplePriorities(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY));
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

and in result I got:

```
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,1,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-4,1,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-4,1,main]: 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-4,1,main]: 3
Thread[pool-1-thread-4,1,main]: 2
Thread[pool-1-thread-4,1,main]: 1
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 3
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 2
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,10,main]: 1
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,1,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-5,1,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,1,main]: 5
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,1,main]: 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,1,main]: 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-5,1,main]: 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,1,main]: 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-5,1,main]: 3
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,1,main]: 3
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,1,main]: 3
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,1,main]: 2
Thread[pool-1-thread-5,1,main]: 2
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,1,main]: 3
Thread[pool-1-thread-5,1,main]: 1
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,1,main]: 1
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,1,main]: 2
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,1,main]: 2
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,1,main]: 1
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,1,main]: 1
```

The author wrote that the last result has the highest priority, but when I run this code in my system I get different priorities and on average often low priorities than high, like above.

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Not sure what your book says should happen, but the results that you provided are what I would expect.  The threads with the higher priority are finishing before the ones with the lower priority.

Comment: It’s not clear what you actually expect. None of the phrases, “the last result has the highest priority”, “I get different priorities” or “on average often low priorities than high” makes sense. Apparently, you have a different idea of what the word “priority” means. Please, rephrase to describe what output you expect and what you think you got instead.